# functions.php de wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

He hecho un plugin para wordpress y ha funcionado, pero parte del código está dentro del functions.php de mi tema hijo y quiero sacarlo, si es posible.
En mi functions hay el siguiente código:

```
// llamada para generar sortcode 
anadir_sortcode();

// función sortcode
function anadir_sortcode(){
    add_shortcode('ideacook','crea_aviso');
}

function crea_aviso(){

    //añadimos nuestro script cookie_script.js y acceso a JQuery
    wp_enqueue_style('estilos', plugins_url().'/coock/includes/estilos.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('miscript', plugins_url().'/coock/includes/miscript.js', array('jquery'));
  .........
  ...........
  ........
  }
```

¿Es posible recolocarlo? ¿dónde? Me gustaría cambiarlo porque el objetivo es simplemente que al instalar el plugin todo funcione y no tenga que tocar nada más.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cree un simple plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name
 *
 * @package     PluginPackage
 * @author      Your Name
 * @copyright   2016 Your Name or Company Name
 * @license     GPL-2.0+
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name: Plugin Name
 * Plugin URI:  https://example.com/plugin-name
 * Description: Description of the plugin.
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      Your Name
 * Author URI:  https://example.com
 * Text Domain: plugin-name
 * License:     GPL-2.0+
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 */

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_example_shortcode', 0 );


function my_plugin_example_shortcode(){
    add_shortcode('ideacook','crea_aviso');
}

function crea_aviso(){

$content = '';   

 //añadimos nuestro script cookie_script.js y acceso a JQuery
    wp_enqueue_style('estilos', plugins_url().'/coock/includes/estilos.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('miscript', plugins_url().'/coock/includes/miscript.js', array('jquery'));

return $content;
  }
```

Comment: El plugin ya está creado y además de esto, lo primero que hace es mostrar otra opción en el menú de administrador de wordpress y poner un formulario. Hasta ahí lo hace bien, lo que no añade o no crea, es el shortcode, que parece que lo ignora.

Comment: Aunque no funcionaba como me dijiste exactamente (o no lo entendí bien), me dio la clave. Lo que tenía que hacer era simplemente meter ese código en otro archivo y "llamarlo" de igual forma que hago con el menú del administrador. Muuuuchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En su forma más simple, podes poner ese mismo código en el cuerpo del plugin.

```
// función sortcode
function anadir_sortcode(){
    add_shortcode('ideacook','crea_aviso');
}

function crea_aviso(){

    //añadimos nuestro script cookie_script.js y acceso a JQuery
    wp_enqueue_style('estilos', plugins_url().'/coock/includes/estilos.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('miscript', plugins_url().'/coock/includes/miscript.js', array('jquery'));
  .........
  ...........
  ........
  }

anadir_sortcode();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Eso ya lo probé y no funciona. Entra el la función anadir_sortcode() pero yo creo que en crea_aviso no; al menos, si yo le pongo un mensaje no me lo muestra

Comment: Aunque estoy perdida, se me ocurre que tal vez no se pueda hacer todo lo que quiero de una vez. Mi plugin, crea una opción en el menú de administrador de wordpress, al pinchar , muestra un formulario y guarda los datos. En base a ello crea un shortcode (debería). La parte del formulario funciona, Si meto la parte del shortcode en el functions.php, también. Si pongo las dos partes en el mismo archivo .php ya no. ¿Puede ser así?.  Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Por si sirve de ayuda

```html
<?php
/*

Plugin Name: I.Cookies
Description: This plugin creates an admin sub-menu in existing menu
Version: 1.0
Author: gema
Author URI:

*/

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'oaf_create_submenu');

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'sortcode', 0 );


function oaf_create_submenu() {

 add_management_page( 'I.Cookies', 'I.Cookies', 'manage_options', 'oaf_create_submenu_plugin', 'oaf_create_submenu_function');

}

function oaf_create_submenu_function () {

 require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'icookies.php';

}

function sortcode(){

 require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'nuevo.php';

}




?>
```

Con esto creo una pestaña en el menú de administrador y voy aun archivo que creará un formulario y por otro lado, iré al archivo que me mostrará un aviso en mi página.
Espero sirva a otros